# Index/Match with Varied Offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Running into some trouble performing an Index/Match where the offset rows could be spaced 1 row apart, 2 rows apart, or 3 rows apart.  Below is an example of the setup:

Sheet1:

```
|   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |
-------------------------------------------------
|       |       |       |       | Apple |       |
-------------------------------------------------
| Ser1  |       |       |       |       |       |
-------------------------------------------------
|       |       |       |       | Orange|       |
-------------------------------------------------
| Ser2  |       | Ser3  |       | Ser4  |       |
-------------------------------------------------
| Ser5  |       |       |       |       |       |
```

Sheet2:

```
|   A   |
---------
| Ser1  |
---------
| Ser2  |
---------
| Ser3  |
---------
| Ser4  |
---------
| Ser5  |
```

I have a list of the serial numbers (ser1, ser2, etc) in another sheet, and I need to match values in Column E where the correct value is above the serial number by 1, 2, or 3 rows.  As you can see, serial numbers could be in column A, C, or E.

Ex:  Ser1 should match on Apple.  Ser2, Ser3, ser4, and Ser5 should match on Orange.

I can't seem to figure out the correct Index/Match that work completely since the offset at the end of the formula is either + or - by a static row number.

Comment: Have you considered VBA for this to transform the data?

Comment: I was hoping to not use VBA only because I'm not very good at it.

Comment: This is just an absolutely awfully setup spreadsheet. Rather than trying to figure out a complicated formula to do what you want, you should set up your spreadsheet in a more user-friendly way.

Comment: I agree 100% but I have no control to how the client sends me the data. If I had my way, they'd send over a db export setup exactly as I need it, but that's often not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rough solution:

In your sheet Make a structure like this:

```
|   A   |   Row  | Lookup
---------
| Ser1  |
---------
| Ser2  |
---------
| Ser3  |
---------
| Ser4  |
---------
| Ser5  |
```

For column Row put:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A$1$:E$5$=A2)*ROW(Sheet1!A$1$:E$5$))
```

this will calculate row in which serial number occures in your data range. Then you may put in Lookup column:

```
=LOOKUP(2,(1/(INDEX(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5,B2-1,1)<>"")),Sheet1!$E$1:$E$5)
```

This formula will lookup for last non-empty cell in column E (please refer [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell) for more comments) in range that is above selected serial number.

This is a partial solution as for "Ser5" you will receive "Ser4". To overcome that issue you may perform additional `Vlookup` on achieved results.

Comment: This is perfect!  I had to go through the source sheet and simply move ser4 and ser5 to the same line as ser1, ser2, and ser3 and then expand my range but the logic and explanation are excellent.  Thank you!

Comment: @dgibbons82 I am glad it helped :)